# What is the C++ way to do this instead of using function pointers?

Tags: c++

I am working on a part of a program that applies different types of filters onto an already read data part of a bitmap image. The method in question gets the data stored in a 2-dim std::vector and furthermore a pointer to the function in which the filter is applied as arguments. By that we can generically apply different filters by using this method.
My question is, are function pointers the only way to achieve this, or does C++ offer a more beautiful and more readable solution to achieve it?

This is the method this question is about. Second argument is the function pointer that is used to access the function in the if/else statement inside the for loops.

```
void SteganoMessage::genFilter(std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t>> *d, uint32_t (*f)(uint32_t, size_t)){
    int count = 0;
    int pixel = getPixel();
    for(auto itOuter = d->begin(); itOuter != d->end(); ++itOuter){
        for(auto itInner = itOuter->begin(); itInner != itOuter->end(); ++itInner){
            if(mode == true)
                *itInner = f(*itInner, sizeof(*itInner));
            else
                *itInner = f(*itInner, this->getImage()->getBitmapHeader()->getBitCount()/8);
            displayProgress(count, pixel);
        }
    }
    displayProgress(0);
}
```

Call of genFilter function:

```
//...
{
    genFilter(data, substB);
}
//...
```

While `substB` is a function of course.

Would be very thankful for a hint that leads me into the right direction where I could research or a code snippet that shows a possible more C++ like way to do it.

Comment: Have a look at `std::function`.

Comment: `std::function` sounds like it would do the trick.

Comment: Or make it a template function.

Comment: You can also use a template, with the help of `std::is_invocable`. Then use `std::invoke` to invoke the Callable.

Comment: I'd advise against using ```std::function``` because it has a performance impact that templates do not have.

Comment: aside: why `mode == true` instead of `mode`, and `sizeof(*itInner)` instead of `sizeof(uint32_t)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Type-preserving

The usual way to pass a function (or things that can be `INVOKE`d) in C++ is by using a template parameter:

```
// version #1
template <typename F>
void func(F f)
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<F, std::uint32_t, std::size_t>);

    // instead of f(*itInner, sizeof(*itInner))
    std::invoke(f, *itInner, sizeof(*itInner));
}
```

You can also use SFINAE to prevent postponing the error to instantiation time. This also enables overloading:

```
// version #2
template <typename F>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F, std::uint32_t, std::size_t>>
    func(F f)
{
    // no need to static_assert here
    std::invoke(f, *itInner, sizeof(*itInner));
}
```

Since C++20, we can use concepts:

```
// version #3
template <std::Invocable<std::uint32_t, std::size_t> F>
void func(F f)
{
    // same as above
}
```

Which can be simplified further, using an abbreviated function template, to:

```
// version #4
void func(std::Invocable<std::uint32_t, std::size_t> auto f)
{
    // same as above
}
```

(This is still a function template rather than an ordinary function.  It is equivalent to version #3.)

## Type-erasing

You can also use `std::function` for type erasure:

```
// version #5
void func(std::function<void(std::uint32_t, std::size_t)> f)
{
    // ...
    f(*itInner, sizeof(*itInner));
}
```

Compared to the type-preserving alternatives (versions #1–4), this approach may reduce code bloat, but may incur runtime overhead for virtual function calling.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the already suggested comments and answer.

But if your question was about finding a way to avoid to pass a raw pointer to function as arguments **and** gain more control over the given filters, I think you can create a wrapping class with a functor that will handle the applied filters.

What is the motivation behind doing this ? Because a raw pointer to function does not give you the guarantee that the function is what you expect. You can pass any function which respect the prototype but is not a real filter and can do anything.

You can solve this problem this way (explanation below the code):

```
enum class FILTER_TYPE {MY_FILTER, MY_OTHER_FILTER};
class Filter
{
    protected:
        FILTER_TYPE f_type;

    public:
        Filter(FILTER_TYPE ft) : f_type(ft)
        {}
        uint32_t operator()(uint32_t a, size_t b) const
        {
            switch(f_type)
            {
                case FILTER_TYPE::MY_FILTER: return my_filter(a, b);
                case FILTER_TYPE::MY_OTHER_FILTER: return my_other_filter(a, b);
            }
        }

    private:
        uint32_t my_filter(uint32_t a, size_t b) const
        {
            return a+static_cast<uint32_t>(b); // completely arbitrary
        }
        uint32_t my_other_filter(uint32_t a, size_t b) const
        {
            return a*static_cast<uint32_t>(b); // completely arbitrary
        }
};
```

As you can see, you define all your different filters in the private section. Then you redefine the `operator()` in order to call the proper filter (selected by the `FILTER_TYPE` attribute).

Then, you can write your function this way:

```
void SteganoMessage::genFilter(std::vector <std::vector <uint32_t>> & data, const Filter & filter)
{
    int count = 0;
    int pixel = getPixel();
    for(auto itOuter = data.begin(); itOuter != data.end(); ++itOuter)
    {
        for(auto itInner = itOuter->begin(); itInner != itOuter->end(); ++itInner)
        {
            if(mode == true)
                *itInner = filter(*itInner, sizeof(*itInner));
            else
                *itInner = filter(*itInner, this->getImage()->getBitmapHeader()->getBitCount()/8);
            displayProgress(count, pixel);
        }
    }
    displayProgress(0);
}
```

This way, you have the guarantee that the argument is a well-defined filter, and you avoid the use of raw pointer to function (that make the code more readable).

I redefined the `operator()` in order to use the `Filter` instance as a function. It makes the code more intuitive in my opinion.

Last thing, I passed the data by reference instead of the address directly.

I hope it can be a good additional information.